# Fetch Record from lighting:dataTable issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

My code :

```
saveDataTable :function(component, event) {
var data = component.get("v.data"); 
var editedRecords1 =  component.find("riderStatusDataTable").get("v.draftValues");
for (var x in data)
 {
 var d = data[x];
 if(d.Form == "Contract Release" ){
  TemporaryArray1.Date_Sent__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Sent;
  TemporaryArray1.Date_Reviewed__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Reviewed;
break;
}
```

JSON Data for : console.log(data);
data->

```
[{"Date_Reviewed":"1989-05-06","Date_Sent":"1989-05-05","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Revision 1","Id":"a0S3F000001bXAIUA2"},
        {"Date_Reviewed":"2019-02-01","Date_Sent":"2019-02-01","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Revision 2","Id":"a0S3F000001bXAJUA2"},
        {"Date_Reviewed":"2020-12-27","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Revision 3","Id":"a0S3F000001bXAKUA2"},
        {"Date_Reviewed":"2020-01-03","Date_Sent":"2020-01-03","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Release","Id":"a0S3F000001bXALUA2"},
        {"Date_Reviewed":"2020-12-29","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Revision 4","Id":"a0S3F000001bXAMUA2"},
        {"Date_Reviewed":"2020-12-30","editable":true,"Form":"Contract Revision 5","Id":"a0S3F000001bXANUA2"},
]        
 
Issue is:
My code is not satisy for  if(d.Form == "Contract Release" ){.

This condition is for only "Contract Release" But , this is apply for other forms also ...Contract Revision1, Contract Revision2...)
My condition is apply for only when Form = Contract Release .
Thanks
```

Comment: Please take some time to format your code with reasonable indentation and bracing style. It's very hard to follow when your code is highly inconsistent. You may also need to [edit] to clarify your problem, and include any additional code that clarifies what you are asking about.

Comment: added comments and code modified. Issue is When i write if condition  if(d.Form == "Contract Release" ){ ////  its also working for other Forms also ...I need to Restrict only for Contract Release Form.

Comment: let releaseData = data.filter(dataVal => dataVal.Form == "Contract Release");
By adding above line , i can able to fetch Contract Release details.   Thanks for support on this

Comment: We don't have threads here, @VidRa. (You can learn more about our format in the [help]). You may write an answer ([answer]) to your own question if it can benefit the rest of the community, or choose to delete your post if you are no longer seeking assistance.